# Completely remove JQuery tinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have initialised tinyMCE like so:

```
$('#text').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script, optional, already loaded in page.
    script_url : '../adminContent/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "table,advimage,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,preview,contextmenu,paste,visualchars",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,forecolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,removeformat,cleanup,code,|,preview,tablecontrols,|,hr,visualaid,|,charmap,iespell",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true
});
```

The code above works perfectly. The problem is when I try to remove tinyMCE.

My remove code is:

```
$('#text').tinymce().execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'text');
```

I've also tried:

```
$('#text').remove();
```

and

```
$('#text').tinymce().remove();
```

The first one doesn't seem to do anything. The last two give me this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined

Although tinymce is loaded by the HTML document, I am loading another script using:

```
$.getScript(viewPath + '/mod/adminContent/js/editContent.js', function(){
    initEditContent(popup);
});
```

popup is a reference to the popup in which tinymce is loaded. It is simply a div that is created using jquery. The contents of the div are loaded using jquery ajax.

The editContent.js looks like this:

```
var contentID;
function initEditContent(popup){
    contentID = $('#contentID').val();

    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, 'text');

    setTimeout(reposition, 50);
    setTimeout(reposition, 150);
    setTimeout(reposition, 250);

    // Submit form
    $('#editTextForm').ajaxForm(
    {
        // Before submit
        beforeSubmit: function(){
            //setPopupMessage(popup, '<div id="loading"><img src="../../img/loading.gif" />&nbsp;Please wait...</div>');
        },

        // Once submit completed
        success: function(responseText){
            tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, 'text');
            //closePopup(popup);

            // Update button with new data
            $('#' + contentID).html(responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `.tinymce().remove()` should do the trick. Can you post a test case on   [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where your problem is reproduced?

Comment: I have edited my initial question to give you more details. Can't use jsFiddle I'm afraid because there are too many external parts required.

Comment: called tinyMCE.remove(); and it gave an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" on line 11264 of tiny_mce_src.js

Comment: So I then tried tinyMCE.remove('text') which actually worked!

BUT - then I tried to load the same popup with the same textarea and it is not initialising tinyMCE any more.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an issue with tinyMCE since version 3.5b3. It works in version 3.5b2.

See [my fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Xpbaab/2) example.

You'll notice that it loads and unloads fine. But change the version to edge or 3.5b3 and you'll get the error when unloading.

As stated on the [tinyMCE bug site](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5136):

> **Description of problem**:
>
> Javascript error on line 13518. t is not defined.
>
> **Steps to reproduce**:
>
> 1. Call tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, idOfTextarea);
>
> **Problem**:
>
> In 3.5b3 you renamed t to self, but didn't rename the used variable in the same line to get the doc.
>
> **Solution**:
>
> Change line 13518 (in function hide()) to: var self = this, doc = self.getDoc();

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. For those that are interested, I loaded tinyMCE in the HTML document, then when I needed to initialise it, I did:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "table,advimage,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,preview,contextmenu,paste,visualchars",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,forecolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,removeformat,cleanup,code,|,preview,tablecontrols,|,hr,visualaid,|,charmap,iespell",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    oninit: function(){
        alert('tinyMCE loaded');
    }
});
```

The above code is called every time the tinyMCE editor is required. I then removed it when I closed the popup like so:

```
tinyMCE.remove('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#text').tinymce().execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'text');
```

where 'text' is the ID of your editor

```
<textarea id='text' .....
```

Comment: Tried that - same error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined

I have included the _src version of tinymce and the error is occurring on line 12318:
`hide : function() {
   var self = this, doc = t.getDoc();
Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined

   // Fixed bug where IE has a blinking cursor left from the editor
   if (isIE && doc)
    doc.execCommand('SelectAll');

   // We must save before we hide so Safari doesn't crash
   self.save();
   DOM.hide(self.getContainer());
   DOM.setStyle(self.id, 'display', self.orgDisplay);
  },`